# I want to be able to locate a value in excel from python and print the value in the next column

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to be able to let a user give me a value in python and then the code finds the value in an excel document and prints the value from the next column.

I can't seem to find any code for it and i am struggling to write it myself, here is my code so far:

```
 dotill = input("would you like to enter till mode?")
 if dotill == "yes":
     barcode = input("please start scanning")
     find (bardcode) in:
         excel_document = openpyxl.load_workbook('scanza.xlsx',data_only=True)
          heet = excel_document['completetransaction']
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Specifically, what part are you having trouble with? What is `find (bardcode) in` supposed to do? (Note that there's a typo there, `barcode` vs. `bardcode`, but that syntax is completely invalid anyway.) You might need to start with some basic Python tutorials to get the basic syntax down. Also, please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/354577)

Comment: Be **very** careful when posting Python questions.  Since indentation is so critical, your question must show the exact code you use.  I edited it and I think I fixed it, but please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look into the [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/) package. It provides an interface with excel.

A part of your question could than be solved using a pandas DataFrame from your excel file that with the path PATH/TO/WORKSHEET beeing searched for the value TESTVALUE which are to replaced in the example below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel(PATH/TO/WORKSHEET)

if TESTVALUE in df.values:
    print('Value in sheet!')
else:
    print('Value not in sheet!')
```

pd.read_excel(path) generates a DataFrame from an excel file. df.values gets you an array of the values. The if statement checks for your value within the array.